# AS3 "TypeError: Error #1009" coming from from inside swf

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a master file with multiple swf's imported.

One of slides has this showing in the output:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Loud2_fla::MainTimeline/moveThatMouse()
```

Code:

```
function moveThatMouse(evt: MouseEvent):void
{
    circle.x = stage.mouseX;
    lightning.x = stage.mouseX;
    circle.y = stage.mouseY;
    lightning.y = stage.mouseY;
    evt.updateAfterEvent();
}
```

and the other this:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Master_fla::MainTimeline/playout()
```

code:

```
playbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playover)
function playover (event:MouseEvent):void{
    playbutton.inside.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
playbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, playout)
function playout (event:MouseEvent):void{
    playbutton.inside.gotoAndPlay(8);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Either `lighting` or `circle` could be null. Are you sure these objects exist within the context of your function (i.e. on the same frame).

Comment: Yeah when I play the swfs individually they work fine, its only when i import them they do this. I have a feeling its to with the fact that the animations (circle & lightning) & sounds are linked to the mouses X/Y position... Its somehow carrying it over into the next scene. :/ thanks for the help by the way. This whole things messing with my head

Comment: Can you post the function `playout()` as well?

Comment: So what happens if you `trace( playbutton )`? Do the same with `lighting` and `circle` and see what comes up as null.

Comment: Also, Master_fla is the master file and Loud_fla is an imported swf...

Comment: After taking away the playout function, it comes up with `Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
 at Sleep2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()`

Comment: Hmm.. Unfortunately the question is moving into a space that I can't cover without knowing how you've constructed most of the project. If possible I would extract the components from the SWFs that you're loading and collate them into one file. You will have far less problems this way :)

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that. Mate, thanks so much for the help. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The errors are telling you that the method `moveThatMouse()` within your FLA `Loud2_fla` and the method `playout()` within `Master_fla` are trying to access members of a variable whose value is `null`. Without seeing those functions in your question, all I can suggest is that you either:

1. Post the content of those functions.
2. Look over those functions and check all of the variables being used within it. See which of those hold a null value.

For clarification, here is how that error can occur:

```
function example(shape:Shape):void
{
    shape.x = 10;
}

// Not assigning an instance of Shape to myShape.
// This makes its value null.
var myShape:Shape;

// Error.
example(myShape);
```